# Updating wrong TextView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I've got three TextViews, plotText, yearText, and directorText. There's also an EditText for the user input.

WHAT SHOULD HAPPEN: When I press the Use Hint button, the Year should appear. When I press the Use Hint button again, the Director should appear.

WHAT IS HAPPENING NOW: When I press the Use Hint button, the Year appears as it should. When I press the button again, the Director label shows up, but directorText (the name of the director) appears in the EditText field instead of the TextView I've assigned it to.

I've checked that my labels are all named correctly and that I'm assigning to the correct one, and I've tried cleaning the project in Eclipse but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

I define the TextViews in onCreate:

```
    TextView yearText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yearText);
    TextView directorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.directorText);
    TextView hintText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hintText);
    TextView plotText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.plotText);
```

Here's the code for the button:

```
public void useHint(View v){
    if (game.numHints == 2){    
        View y = findViewById(R.id.yearLabel);
        y.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        yearText.setText(currentMovie.year);
        game.numHints--;
        hintText.setText("Hints Remaining: "+game.numHints);
    }else if (game.numHints == 1){
        View d = findViewById(R.id.directorLabel);
        d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        directorText.setText(currentMovie.director);
        game.numHints--;
        hintText.setText("Hints Remaining: "+game.numHints);
        // remove button
        View b = findViewById(R.id.hintButton);
        b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="Andrea.guessthetitle.ActivityGuessPage" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plotLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Plot:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plotText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plotLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plotLabel"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minHeight="500px"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plotText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plotText"
        android:text="Year: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yearText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yearLabel"
        android:text="Director: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/directorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:text="TextView" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/directorLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Guess:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/guessInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/guessButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/endButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guessLabel"
        android:onClick="submitGuess"
        android:text="Guess" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hintButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/guessButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/guessButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="useHint"
        android:text="Use Hint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hintButton"
        android:text="Hints Remaining: 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/endButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="endGame"
        android:text="End Game" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a screenshot (nothing has been typed into the text field, that text appears there when I click the hint button, which has now disappeared, as it's supposed to do): 
[image]

Comment: Try clean & build your project. Sometimes the ids do not get updated properly.

Comment: Aw man, I apparently ran Source -> Clean Up instead of Project -> Clean like I should have. :( It's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a dumb question, because it was just a simple mistake. I'll leave it up though, in case anyone else may run into it. I can't be the only one who makes small mistakes like this (hopefully!).

**The problem was, I had run Source -> Clean Up instead of Project -> Clean.** Running the correct clean did the trick. Thanks to @Eugen Pechanec.